# Connect custom-post-type posts to a page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type **Team member**, which is displayed on contact page. I would also like the ability of connecting one or more team members to a regular page. So that the team member is displayed with contact information for just their specific area.

What is the best method/solution for achieving this? Is there any good plugin or should I use categories and links somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're trying to achieve but if you'd like to output your custom post items to a specific page, you can create a custom page template and assign it to a new page.

Let's say you wanted to output all team members to a specific page, you could save this as a template file to your theme directory:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: List Team Members
*/
?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'team-member', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

   <div class="team-member">
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><!-- display post title -->
       <p><?php the_content(); ?></p><!-- display post content-->
       <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'team-member-contact-info',true) ?></p><!-- display custom field 'team-member-contact-info' -->
   </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can be more selective by adjusting the qp_query. Also, the get_post_meta part is in case your custom post type is using custom fields. You'll also want to include the calls for the header and footer plus any other html needed to match your current theme but this should give you the idea.

Once that's uploaded to your theme directory, create a new WP page via the editor and select the "List Team Members" template and hit publish.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, That part is allready coverd. Now Im trying to associate certain team members to specif pages so on page production I would like to show all team members that are in production. I currently do this by catagories but not sure if there is a smarter way?